# Android beveled/inset border

Tags: android, border, insets, layer-list

I've seen on other apps people using the really nice looking borders/dividers that look like they are inset.[image]

Something like that. I'd like to create one of my own using an XML drawable and I'm a little confused about how it needs to be done. I know I'm going to have to use a layer-list and I even found another question that describes how to write the XML here: [Create gradient border in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098262/create-gradient-border-in-android)

Going off of that question though, I don't understand the last part of step 3:

// specify here where you want to have a stroke(top, left, right, bottom)

```
android:top="3dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="3dp"
android:left="3dp" />
```

Which file does that code go in an on which element?

Comment: why layer-list? it could be simple .png or .9.png

Comment: I don't have one and have no artistic ability to create one.

Comment: its just a tiny 1x3 pixels sized image...

Comment: To create an inset effect? Link to steps?

Comment: never seen any tutorial for that, just some experience in gimp

Comment: a good place to create shadow and any type of 9patch stuff 
http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have learned is to use a 9-patch background. 9-patch backgrounds are how Android achieve button styles. In my case I had a custom view that I wanted to behave/be triggered like a button (to imitate an HTML5 equivalent) but I created it off a FrameLayout > RelativeLayout > [controls] view. I then created a background using graphic tool styled the way I want. Imported it into Android Studio > raw folder. Right-click to 'Creaate 9-Patch...'. After adjusting the 9-patch that I stored in /drawable folder, I then used it is a background for my custom view. It gave me a perfect result.