# Android shape border with gradient and middle transparent

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a round corner border, where border with gradient.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20870948/5648521) is working.But My page is using a image as background which is also with gradient. I need to show background image from middle of the filed. I want to create just like below image:[image]

Answer (score 2):

> round_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke
    android:width="4dp"
    android:color="@color/transparent" />
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#374533"
        android:centerColor="#432727"
        android:endColor="#222430"
        android:angle="135"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

> round_border.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<gradient
    android:startColor="#efe301"
    android:centerColor="#7dc17b"
    android:endColor="#01dae6"
    android:angle="180"/>
<corners android:radius="10dp" />
```

> result_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:drawable="@drawable/round_border"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/round_background" />

</layer-list>
```

Here, you can set android:width="4dp" in round_background.xml to set size of your border. use result result_drawable.xml where you want.. 
Enjoy. :}

Comment: I have background also with gradient color, so how to match with background color?

Comment: Worked for me for custom tab layout

Comment: that is not desired result, the inner background is not really transparent

Comment: You would need a different round_background.xml for each position on the background.. That does not make sense..