# Android drawable circle with gradient

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I make drawable circle with gradient? I would like something that looks like this

[image]

Actually I managed to do this :

[image]

With the following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#1E90FF"/>
            <size android:width="60dp" android:height="60dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: @B001ᛦ : Not at all, I want a linear gradient in a circle and not a circular gradient

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322955/android-shape-border-with-gradient-and-middle-transparent

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=how+to+make+border+grafdien+in+andoird&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8