# is an android shape with a gradient border and transparent middle possible?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, drawable

I am looking to make the middle of the button transparent with the gradient border, I am not sure how this can be done using the layer-list. I know the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322955/android-shape-border-with-gradient-and-middle-transparent) already exists but the answer was not sufficient as they were just adding another gradient inside. The middle has to be transparent so that the gradient background will be seen.

[image]

This is the code for my current button which has my background for the center.

```
<layer-list>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:innerRadius="8dp">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/secondary_button_roundness" />
            <gradient
                android:startX="0"
                android:startY="0"
                android:endX="20"
                android:endY="0"
                android:endColor="@color/primaryGradientStart"
                android:startColor="@color/primaryGradientEnd"
                android:angle="180" >
            </gradient>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:innerRadius="8dp">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/secondary_button_roundness" />
            <solid android:color="@color/Background" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve this using jetpack compose then you can use interoperability API

```
@Composable
fun SetRing() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Transparent)
            .border(
                2.dp,
                Brush.linearGradient(
                    colors = listOf(
                        Color.Yellow,
                        Color.Blue
                    )
                ),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
            )
            .padding(6.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = "Hiphop")
    }
}
```

interoperability API,
in XML file

```
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
    android:id="@+id/compose_interest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

[output]

[image]